# How to show $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |a_i| < \epsilon$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In the book of *Complex Analysis* by Conway, at page 30 it is given that

[image]

However, I'm not able to show the existence of such an $N$. I mean isn't the convergence of the series implies that $\exists N$ s.t $\forall n > N$,

$$-\epsilon < \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| - z_0 < \epsilon.$$ Looking at the picture, the sum $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |a_i| $ looks also less than the epsilon, but I cannot show it mathematically.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tail_of_Convergent_Series_tends_to_Zero   Have a look at the proof here. This answers your question.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|$ then $\{T_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. hence it is laso a Cauchy sequence. So there exits an integer $N$ such that  $|T_{n+m}-T_n| <\epsilon /2$ for all $n \geq N$ for all $m$. This means $\sum_{i=n}^{n+m} |a_i| <\epsilon /2$  for alll $m$ . Let $m \to \infty$.

Comment: you fix the upper bound of the sum with $N$, and then claim that $|T_{n+m} - T_m|< \epsilon /2$ $\forall n > N$ ? I didn't get it.

Comment: @onurcanbektas There was  typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varepsilon'\in(0,\varepsilon)$. Since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert a_n\rvert$ converges, then, by the Cauchy criterion, there is a natural $N$ such that$$m\geqslant n\geqslant N\implies\sum_{k=n}^m\lvert a_n\rvert<\varepsilon'.$$But then$$\sum_{k=N}^\infty\lvert a_n\rvert\leqslant\varepsilon'<\varepsilon.$$